# Cannot set properties of undefined (setting 'onclick')

Tags: javascript, list, class, onclick, undefined

Getting error that onclick is applied on undefined, although i am passing the node element.

html

```
<div class="gallery">
          <img src="image1.png" id="prdImg" />
          <div class="control">
            <span class="btn active"></span>
            <span class="btn"></span>
            <span class="btn"></span>
          </div>
        </div>
```

JS

```
const prdImg = document.getElementById("prdImg");
const btn = document.getElementsByClassName("btn");

for (let i = 0; i <= btn.length; i++) {
  btn[i].onclick = function () {
    prdImg.src = `image${i + 1}.png`;
    for (bt of btn) {
      bt.classList.remove("active");
    }
    this.classList.add("active");
  };
}
```

Comment: Script is probably getting executed before HTML loads. Check whether `<script>` tag is placed after `<div>`  or add defer attribute <script src="pathToJS" defer>

Comment: `<` instead of `<=`

Answer (score 1):

In the for loop, change `i <= btn.length` for `i < btn.length`.

```
const prdImg = document.getElementById("prdImg");
const btn = document.getElementsByClassName("btn");

for (let i = 0; i < btn.length; i++) {
  btn[i].onclick = function () {
    prdImg.src = `image${i + 1}.png`;
    for (bt of btn) {
      bt.classList.remove("active");
    }
    this.classList.add("active");
  };
}
```

Comment: yeah! got it thanks silly mistake